# App splash screen is only shown over an install/run of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen

I implement a splash screen with this tutorial: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

If I install/run the App over Android Studio I can see the splash screen on the startup of the App. Now I close the App over Android Studio or over "close all Apps" from my phone and I want to start the App directly over the icon in my phone. But than I can't see the splash screen. There comes only the white screen which comes before I implement the splash screen. If I make changes in the MainActivity - these changes are on the phone.

Somebody knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this intent filter with Launcher is only in your SplashActivity in manifest.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Otherwise provide your manifest and SplashActivity code.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I have to remove the intent-filter node completely from the MainActivity.

Comment: My pleasure!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This because you are running debug build. Try to run realese build in your device.
In release build enable shrink resource, minify and apply proguard

Below sample exmaple

```
minifyEnabled true
       shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.txt'

        zipAlignEnabled true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Was not the solution for my current problem but I didn't know that. I will use it in my App.